# UnsatisfiedLinkError when App is installed in /system/app folder

Tags: android, android-library, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I copied my app apk in the /system/app folder & restarted my device. When I start the app I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError for the libraries that I use in the app. Is there any specific way to load libraries when installing app in the /system/app folder.